Writing two double integrals as one
Let a straight solid has its base in the plane $xy$ and bounded above by the continuous function $f(x,y)$ such that the volume of the solid is given by
$$V=\int_{0}^{2}\int_{-y}^{0}f(x,y)dxdy+\int_{2}^{4}\int_{y-4}^{0}f(x,y)dxdy$$
May I write the volume as follows?
Since
$$\int_{-y}^{0}dx=-\int_{0}^{y}f(x,y)dx$$
then
$$V=\int_{0}^{4}\int_{y-4}^{y}2f(x,y)dxdy$$

$$\int_{-y}^0 \cdots \neq - \int_0^y$$ Think about that statement geometrically. What lines do they represent?

@NinadMunshi Sorry, I didn't understand.

Have you drawn a region of integration before?

To be honest, no.

I think that lies at the core of your difficulties the past few posts. You have to be able to visualize to get better at multivariable calculus, bounds are not just algebraic curiosities you can manipulate as you did. To help you get started, you should understand what the bounds of integration mean. So far they have always been from a point to a point. But now with double integrals, the innermost bounds will always go from a curve to a curve (in the $xy$ plane). Here, $x=y$ and $x=-y$ represent completely different curves in the $xy$ plane. They cannot be interchanged.

For each of the two integrals, draw the lines and then connect them using the fact that $y$ must be bounded by the range provided by the outer bounds. Which quadrant will these regions live in?

To answer the titular question: Yes, you may combine the integrals into one by writing$$\int_{y=0}^4\int_{x=\max{-y,y-4}}^0f(x,y),dx,dy\equiv\int_{y=0}^4\int_{x=\lvert y-2\rvert-2}^0f(x,y),dx,dy$$though that's not a particularly useful thing to do. Much better to change the order of integration.
